# nginx to return json for 504

Tags: nginx, configuration, microservices, nginx-reverse-proxy

Configuring nginx for other error codes(Except 504) work perfectly fine and returns my custom json object instead of HTML.

```
 error_page 504 =504 @res;

     location @res {
           default_type application/json;
          return 504 '{"code":"504","message":"Server Timeout"}';
      }
```

But in case of 504 alone, it gives only the HTML.

Should we handle 504 differently? The goal is nginx should return json and not a html.

Comment: This does not look like `java` to me. Are you sure you added the right tag(s)?

Comment: springboot services are the underlying services in nginx server.